# Python 3.9.6 - Trying to set flag to False. Keep getting error TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, while-loop, flags

In the code below I'm trying to set the 'active' flag to False. This fails. The program should stop running when age is 'quit', however continues.

I can see the error is because I'm trying to compare a string and an integer but I don't know why the program is reaching that point. Help appreciated.

```
active = True

while active:
    age = input('Enter age for ticket price: ')
    if age == 'quit':
        active = False
    else:
        age = int(age)

    if age < 3:
        print("You get in free!")
    elif age < 13:
        print("Your ticket is £10.")
    elif age > 13:
        print("Your ticket is £15.")
```

Error message -
if age < 3:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Put a continue after active = False

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the active flag, you have to avoid the line:

```
if age < 3:
```

Since age is now a string (equal to 'quit').  Try this:

```
active = True

while active:
    age = input('Enter age for ticket price: ')
    if age == 'quit':
        active = False
    else:
        age = int(age)

        if age < 3:
            print("You get in free!")
        elif age < 13:
            print("Your ticket is £10.")
        elif age > 13:
            print("Your ticket is £15.")
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I missed the indentation of the comparisons

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the loop after receiving the quit signal, either with `continue` after `active=False` or simply `break`, then you don't even need the active flag anymore and you can write `while True:`

The reason why it breaks is because your code inside the loop is stil executed until the end, and you compare `'quit' < 3`

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind explaining why continue is needed when working with integers? A similar program with only strings would work fine without continue. Also, I know about using break. However, I am purposely using flags as a different way of breaking out of while loops, even if the code is simple and breaks are probably a better way to do it.

Comment: the code is executed sequentially, and the forloop will run until the end, even if you set the active flag to false. Using only strings will also continue, you probably just don't get the error since you compare string with string and not int with string.